# Как чат ВК динамически загружает более ранние сообщения?

Tags: javascript, api, вконтакте, chat, чат

Я делаю чат, который бы мог содержать большое количество сообщений. И появилась необходимость динамически подгружать сообщения, когда пользователь будет скроллить чат вверх (как, например, чат Вконтакте).

В мою голову пришла идея использования чанков (блок из нескольких сообщений), но тут нужно менять бизнес логику сервера (делать запрос с количеством загружаемых чанков)

Тем не менее, если посмотреть, например, [API Вконтаке](https://vk.com/dev/messages.get), то можно увидеть, что у них все реализовано по-другому (без чанков). Если коротко, то нужно включить в параметры переменную `last_message_id` - id сообщения, с которого нужно получить данные.

И вот ко мне в голову пришла идея дать клиенту самому использовать что-то наподобие чанков, используя `last_message_id`.

И теперь возникает вопрос, как узнать какие id у сообщений?

**Первый вариант**, назначать id сообщений относительно чата (*то есть первое сообщение в чата с id = 1, второй id = 2 ...*), но таким образом, теряется уникальность сообщения (хотелось бы чтобы у каждого сообщения был уникальный идентификатор, чтобы потом можно было ссылаться).

Но это не единственная проблема, что если например сообщение удалят, тогда id не будут последовательными и мы не сможем узнать сколько сообщений подгружаем.

**Второй вариант**, костыльный, создать дополнительное вспомогательное API. Но этот вариант мне не нравится и хотелось бы обойтись без него.

Говоря о методе API, хотелось бы ограничится параметрами `last_msg_id` и `chat_name`.

В общем, хотелось бы узнать **как это реализовано в ВК** или как сделать чат, который минимально нагружал сервер (малое количество запросов и размер ответа)?

К слову, для API я использую JAX-RS (Jersey), а на фронтенде ReactJS

Comment: «id не будут последовательными» — это вообще не проблема, никто нигде никогда не считает количество сообщений по id

Comment: @andreymal да, скорее всего, вы правы. Правда, я пока не знаю как это можно сделать не используя логику на стороне сервера. И если не узнать количество сообщений, то создавать чанки будет сложнее, так как могут быть избыточные запросы (например, с пустыми чанками).

Comment: Никто нигде никогда не отказывается от логики на стороне сервера) Зачем себя искусственно ограничивать?

Comment: @andreymal :) Похоже, и вправду придется об этом задуматься.

Comment: Что за бред про чанки? Вы сообщения пользователей каким образом храните то? Инкремент у вас есть? Вам всего-лишь необходимо получить ID сообщений и от него отталкиваться. Пролистнули вверх, получили последний ID, сделали запрос относительно его и подгрузили остальную часть. Всё. Что за велосипеды с чанками.

Comment: @MoloF видимо я не так объяснил или термины не те использовал. По сути, я хотел сделать тоже самое, что предлагаете вы, но под чанками я имел в виду некоторое количество сообщений, которое необходимо получить (не делать n запросов для получения n сообщений). Ну, с этим понятно. В общем, я так и сделал. А необходимость подгрузки новых сообщений выяснял через уровень скролла. Спасибо за ответ.
P.S инкремент по ID сообщений есть.